# События мыши в PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, мышь

Каким образом нужно переопределить методы `mouseEvent`, чтобы стало возможным изменение цвета кнопки только по нажатию на нее мышью (то есть не "нажал и отпустил", а "нажал и удерживаешь")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо переопределить два метода:

```
class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('mousePressEvent')

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('mouseReleaseEvent')
```

---

**Update**

> можете подсказать как именно нужно переопределить mouseReleaseEvent, я пытался и у меня не вышло. не знаю как обработать именно нажатие и удерживание

Переопределять методы надо в классе наследованном от `QPushButton`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText('Button')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('mousePressEvent')
        self.setStyleSheet('background: #3A4256;')

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('mouseReleaseEvent')
        self.setStyleSheet('')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.btn = PushButton(self) 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.btn)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MainWindow()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете подсказать как именно нужно переопределить mouseReleaseEvent, я пытался и  у меня не вышло. не знаю как обработать именно нажатие и удерживание

Comment: @Олег я добавил решение вашего вопроса

Comment: @ S. Nick У меня событие срабатывает, когда я отпускаю кнопку. А нужно чтобы как только я нажал (но не отпустил) , кнопка поменяла цвет. Возможно, ваш код работает у вас именно так, но у меня нет(возможно я что то упустил)

Comment: @Олег что значит, что мой код работает `возможно так` ? Вы пробовали запустить мой пример?

Comment: .Пробовал. Работает. Я вставил ваши переопределенные методы в свой код. Это сработало только при нажатии на само окно, а не на кнопки(если нажать на нужную мне кнопку и удерживать, print("mousePressEvent") сработает только в том случае, если я переведу курсор на другую кнопку и перестану удерживать)

Comment: @Олег   `Каким образом нужно переопределить методы mouse...` я вам ответил. Пример рабочий. Примите решение отвечает ли мой ответ на ваш вопрос. Если у вас другие вопросы связанные с вашим кодом - задайте `Новый вопрос` и приложите ваш пример, который демонстрирует проблему.